# Ubuntu 12.04 dual screen - live version OK but does not work after installation

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, dualhead

I have a desktop machine, a bit old Intel Core 2 4400 (64bit), with nVidia GeForce 7900, two Iiyamas, one 2403, one 2202.

The problem is that everything works fine under Live version -- the display applet sees both monitors and is able to recognise them and sets the resolution properly. Then after installation the display applet cannot recognise the configuration anymore -- it says it is a single 'Laptop' display with screen resolution up to 1280x768 or something.

Deleting the xorg.conf helps only a little -- one can set the proper 1920x1200 resolution, but that's all -- 'display' applet still see only the single 'Laptop' display.

I'd like to copy the Live version configuration but I am not aware how to find out the differences between both configurations --

My question is how to check which package is installed and how to check where to find its config files to copy?

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but try the nvidia setting tool to set it as you like

Comment: Is't is surely possible to use two monitrs without any problem. I have 3 monitors with 2 nVidia VGAs and at work I have one AMD card and two monitors. I am convinced that there is just some minor issue. Could you paste Xorg file contents? Did you try to use nvidia settings as sudo?

Answer (score 2):

Just curious, did you open Nvidia as Root?  `sudo nvidia-settings` if not, changes CAN'T be saved, as you need to be in the utility as root.